# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'lodash-es'

Tags: angular, lodash, package.json, definitelytyped

In my Angular 8 TypeScript code I was importing lodash directy (e.g. `import * as _ from 'lodash';`). In my `package.json` I had `"lodash": "^4.17.15"`.

I decided to install the `@types/lodash-es` module and import the specific lodash functions that way (e.g. `import { map } from 'lodash-es';`). It is better because it saves runtime space and also uses the standard Angular/TypeScript import mechanism.

However, now when I run a build I am getting this error:

`Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'lodash-es'`

How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In addition to installing the `@types/lodash-es` module, the existing `"lodash": "^4.17.15"` module needs to be replaced with `"lodash-es": "^4.17.15"`

This is because `@types/lodash-es` requires `lodash-es` and not `lodash`. This is obvious once you know it but I missed it originally.

Comment: For any time travelers this also works with other libs such as `lodash.clone` and whatever additions have been made since now. Also, we need food, water, top 3 stock picks, and a new flux capacitor.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

> npm install @types/lodash-es --save-dev

If after this you will  have the same problem please check the package.json that you have in dependencies

> **"lodash-es": "^4.17.20"**

when you dont have, just write and  run npm install in cmd .
This work for me.

Answer (score 0):

you can update your node__modules by npm update. It has removed the error for my case.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).